# Getting the latest version of Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

It looks like I can use:

```
//getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css
//getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js
```

to automatically use the latest version of bootstrap.

Does anybody ever do that?

Answer (score 4):

You have CDN's that have a similar functionality ([BootstrapCDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com) for example), but I wouldn't recommend to automatically get the latest version. If the new version breaks something you wouldn't know it until it's too late.

Besides, what would the benefit be? Anything major is very likely to break something, and anything minor is, well, minor.

Comment: You know: that logic is irrefutable. But as Captain Kirk would say to Spock, sometimes humans don't act rationally.

Comment: I created a HTML shell for testing locally and I want latest version always (don't wanna change version manually over time and don't care if some features are broken)

Answer (score 1):

At http://getbootstrap.com/, they say

> "Downloads are pulled directly from the latest committed code on
>   GitHub, and as a result our docs may at times be out of sync."

Your page will load faster if you get your bootstrap from their site but it may be outdated.

Hope it helped!